# How to set get private members of a class: looking for a better approach

Tags: c++, private-members

I have a class with scores of private members. I have defined public functions for setting and getting their values. Since for each of these private members, I have defined a set of set/get functions, my code has become too busy. I am sure there should be a more smart way of dealing with this scenario, so any idea?

Comment: @JeJo I have to access all those private members from outside of the class. So, they are all needed! I am looking for a better approach. What I had in mind was to define an enum that defines an index for each parameter, so I will only have one setter-getter in which there is a bunch of if-else or switch cases

Comment: Make the member variables public?

Comment: @Quentin firstly, is it a good practice? if yes, under which circumstances. Second, I have to apply some value check every time I get/set a parameter

Comment: @JalilNourisa The good practice is to design classes in such a way that no other class needs to access private members. If another class needs to access private stuff of a class, then the responsibilities are wrongly placed. Maybe methods shall be moved or something else shall be refactored. If you find yourself in a place where a getter and setter are needed and design cannot be changed, don't lie - the member is not private at all, because you have a getter and setter for it. Make it `public`.

Comment: "I have defined public functions for setting and getting their values" You need to identify the book or the person who suggested to you it would be a good idea, and make sure you never trust their advice again. Then throw away your design and start over. Design a class that *does* something, not a class that *has* a lot of stuff.

Comment: "What I had in mind was to define an enum that defines an index for each parameter" This is an **EXTREMELY BAD** idea.

Comment: IMO, this question is too broad. Books have been written on how to design classes properly, and a single SO answer cannot give a definitive answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all check if all variables need Getter and Setter Methods.(As the comment suggested) After that check if you can set some variables together with one method and after all you should check if you architecture approach is the correct one or if smash to many functionalities into one class.